# Adobe CEP Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined"

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

I am trying to build a very basic extension for Adobe Premier Pro which simply opens up a single file but the app object is not being exposed in the object environment of javascript.

Here is my code

.debug:

```
<ExtensionList>
    <Extension Id="com.my.test.panel">
        <HostList>
            <Host Name="PPRO" Port="8088"/>
        </HostList>
    </Extension>
</ExtensionList>
```

index.js

```
// csInterface object
var csInterface = new CSInterface();

// Get a reference to the Open button
var openButton = document.querySelector("#open-button");

// Add click event listener to the Open button
openButton.addEventListener("click", openDoc);

// Bind Click event to the Open button
var openButton = document.querySelector("#open-button");
openButton.addEventListener("click", openDoc);

// Function to open the document
function openDoc() {
  var filePath = "C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/1-a.png";
  csInterface.evalScript(openImage(filePath));
}

// Open Image
function openImage(filePath) {
    var filePathArr = [filePath];
    var file = new File(filePathArr, "PNG");
    app.open(file);
}
```

index.html

```
    <!-- 1) Simple HTML UI elements to get us started -->
    <h1>Your first panel</h1>

    <!-- 2) A button -->
    <button id="open-button">Open</button>

    <!-- 3) Add your script dependencies here, including CEP's CSInterface.js library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CSInterface.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

I am primarily following guides from these links:

- [Starter Guide](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides)
- [PremierPro Script Guide](https://ppro-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/introduction/index.html)
- [ExtendScript Guide](https://extendscript.docsforadobe.dev/index.html)
- [CEP Resources](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources)

I followed all the guidelines but not sure what I am missing that is giving me the app error, in the localhost:8088 it is showing the extension UI but with the app error.

I am using `CSInterface - v9.2.0`

Comment: I'm not an expert in CEP. So it's a guess. `app.open()` is an Extendscript part. As far as I understand to run Extend script from CEP you have to convert the Extendscript part into a string and then to evaluate the srting in CEP. Something like this: `var script = "app.open(file)"; CSInterface.evalScript(script, evalScriptCallback);` See here: https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_8.x/Documentation/CEP%208.0%20HTML%20Extension%20Cookbook.md#invoke-point-products-scripts-from-html-extension

Comment: @YuriKhristich I tried using evalScript function in hope that it will have access to the `app` object but no matter what code I put in its parameters, it does not respond in any ways. but If I put without codes like this: `CSInterface.evalScript(console.log("hello"))` gets triggered but if I put the app reference without quote then it throws the app not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this was my mistake, I was trying to run `app` (application object) in the `client`/`index.js` file but actually it is suppose to be in the `host`/`index.jsx` file and `CSInterface.evalScript` is used to access the functions defined in the `host` /`index.jsx`